# Could not initialize class com.tridion.web.Admin

Tags: 2013, smarttarget

i am getting below error when browsing the page i have published the page with .aspx extension . i am actually creating static page using smart target 2014 and tridion 2013 SP1.cd_wai_conf.xml is already available in config folder

java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError

Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

================================================

ClassPath           : C:\websites\SmartTargetTest\bin\bin
   ClassPath           : C:\websites\SmartTargetTest\bin\bin

============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although everyone above has mentioned about missing the JAR file and checking whether you are missing it - The most important thing is that you must check and put the JAR file and/or configs at the right place - In case you are having a `bin\lib` and `bin\config` in the executing website location, then this will supersede over the `bin\lib` and `bin\config` folder available in your Content Delivery setup.

Ensure you have these missing JAR files and/or configs in these directories of your executing application if this is the case along with your Content Delivery setup

Comment: finally issue is resolved and page is rendered ...

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a JAR. Check again if you deployed all the SDL and third party JARs for:

- SDL SmartTarget
- SDL Tridion Content Delivery

Don't focus too much on the `...\bin\bin` classpath, it looks weird but in my experience this just means a JAR in ...\bin\lib is missing.

If fixing the JARs does not work, take a step back and get a [test page](https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/b858f0397d83ec732d3d), with for example just some SmartTarget controls working. That might give you additional hints.

Comment: Below are the jar files which i have copied in my website
smarttarget_core.jar
 smarttarget_entitymodel.jar
commons-codec.jar
 commons-discovery.jar
 commons-httpclient.jar
 commons-lang.jar
 commons-logging.jar
 jdom.jar
 jersey-client.jar
 jsr181-api.jar
 oro.jar


 Tridion.SmartTarget.dll
 Tridion.Smarttarget.Interop.dll

Comment: When i am using .html extension page then it is not giving any error . Also generating the smart target related tag checkd in view source but not rendering any content on page

Comment: Is your page not using any Tridion controls? You do not have the Tridion content delivery api role jars.

Comment: I have followed the below link to configure the .net web application 
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-0071E368-984B-43DD-94C9-726727B5BD5B#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-0071E368-984B-43DD-94C9-726727B5BD5B.xml&docid=GUID-0071E368-984B-43DD-94C9-726727B5BD5B&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-0071E368-984B-43DD-94C9-726727B5BD5B

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this issue, my fix was a little different so i'll add it here.

In my cd_wai_conf.xml file the path to my licence file was commented out.

I simply uncommented the line, ensuring the path to cd_licence.xml was correct and restarted the webservice to fix it.

hope this helps someone out there :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the pre-requisites for SmartTarget is a working CD installation.

So hopefully you didn't *only* install the SmartTarget JAR files and DLLs :)

Anyway, com.tridion.web.Admin is part of *cd_wai.jar* which you are apparently missing but have configured CD to use. Either copy over the JAR file (along with any other ones you are missing from Tridion Content Delivery), or make sure your configuration does not reference WAI at all.