# static page using smart target 2014 and tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, smarttarget

I have build a static page using tridion 2013 sp1 and smart target 2014. the page view source is generating the smarttarget related tags but nothing is rendered onto the page

```
<smarttarget:Query AllowDuplicates="true" Publication="tcm:0-1048-1" runat="server">
  <smarttarget:Promotions MaxItems="10" Region="Sidebar" runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
      <smarttarget:PromotionalItems runat="server"> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
    <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:1048-7183-64" ComponentURI="<%# Eval(&quot;ComponentUri&quot;) %>" TemplateURI="<%# Eval(&quot;TemplateUri&quot;) %>"/> 
      </ItemTemplate> 
    </smarttarget:PromotionalItems> 
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FallbackContent></FallbackContent> 
  </smarttarget:Promotions>
</smarttarget:Query>
```

i have tried this on both .aspx and .html Page template but no luck. and from fredhopper end  file is in process folder whenever i publish the page `C:\fredhopper\data\instances\SmartTarget\data\xml\processed\batch`

Also i have configured the app server to execute the html page when using .html PT

Comment: I formatted the code you supplied for making it readable, and it looks to me like you have a bit of an issue there with too many `</ItemTemplate>` tags

Comment: @Hem: How are those SmartTarget controls generated? Did you put them on the .aspx page, or are they generated by a TBB?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser or in the logback logs?

Comment: @JanH: Tags are generated by TBB and there is no error Just blank page rendered

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead. I change the `</ItemTemplate>` before `<tridion:ComponentPresentation>` into `<ItemTemplate>`.

```
<smarttarget:Query AllowDuplicates="true" Publication="tcm:0-1048-1" runat="server">
  <smarttarget:Promotions MaxItems="10" Region="Sidebar" runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
      <smarttarget:PromotionalItems runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
    <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:1048-7183-64" ComponentURI="<%# Eval(&quot;ComponentUri&quot;) %>" TemplateURI="<%# Eval(&quot;TemplateUri&quot;) %>"/> 
      </ItemTemplate> 
    </smarttarget:PromotionalItems> 
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FallbackContent></FallbackContent> 
  </smarttarget:Promotions>
</smarttarget:Query>
```

Comment: Tried the code which u have mentioned but no luck getting error now  
<JavaException>
 <Type>java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError</Type>
 <Message><![CDATA[Could not initialize class com.tridion.web.Admin

Comment: Great! That means you fixed it and now run into the next issue. The NotClassDefFoundError sounds familiar: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/10937/could-not-initialize-class-com-tridion-web-admin

Answer (score 0):

Please write any thing inside  and see is it getting displayed or not.
If Fallback Content is getting dipalyed then ther are two conditions.
1. Trigger are not gettign triggered.
2. No data in FredHopper. (You said its there.)

So try creating a Promo Content in same publication where you are applying Trigger in SmartTarget,

SmartTarget wont pick Item from Parent Publication.

If that doesn,t works we can work together/Screen Sharing to look into the issue.